# Choice of logging framework for open source java project

Tags: java, open-source, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

Recently I published my open source [java game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) code to github and faced the following dilemma "which logging should I use".I want my library to have most "ease of use" for end developer. I hope to create a pseudo-wiki out of this question so that others facing same issue can have a single point of reference.

1) If your open source project is a simple java library, what are the options available for logging.
a. Use your own logging logic
b. Print to console,err
c. Use a library like log4j, slf4j etc
2) What are the best practices? Which one of the above is the general preference for open source libraries?
3) For some of the famous logging frameworks out there, like log4j, slf4j, commons-logging etc what are known issues that need to be considered while selecting it as your logging library.
4) Will my choice of logging framework impact another library which uses mine? Is there possibility of incompatibilities if I use a specific library?

If you have some additional comments like "log only to console", "dont use logging" etc then please justify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Never** write directly to console ;) If someone uses your library he might want to have console for himself, not for your logs.

slf4j (and commons-logging) is not a logging framework. It's an abstraction layer which lets you program vs one interface and use the implementation of your (or the end user of your library) choice, be it log4j, java logging or whatever. I'd go for that as it leaves the choice of implementation up to the user.

Comment: Is there any compatibility issues with using slf4j/commons-logging? Meaning, if I use it in my library(a) and some other library(b) uses different version of slf4j and developer is using both a and b then will there be issues.

Comment: @Abe I'm not aware of any. Obviously if there are two versions of slf4j used there may be conflicts, but I guess you can then throw out the older one or just let the classloader decide what to use. They try to have a stable api so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I was using SLF4J as a facade and Logback as logging implementation. I was wery happy with this configuration. I was able to redirect some third-party libraries logging to Logback. They were using different logging techniques.